# Getting Google Doc innerHTML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-docs

Good morning! I'm making an extension for Google Chrome. What I need is to get the text from any editable input or div of the element that the user is editing.

For example, if he edits a text input, I must process the information the user types in real time. This is solved with keyup in the doc and then a document.activeElement.

It works well on all websites except Google Docs. The problem is that Google Doc itself is not an input or a div, but a canvas. Does anyone have any idea of how I can access the content of the sheet?

[image]

I have tried with a document.querySelector('.kix-canvas-tile-content').innerHTML but it returns an empty string.

Thanks

Comment: As a workaround while I am checking other ways you can get the text from Google Docs, have you reviewed the option to publish a Google Doc to the web and use the embed data ?

Comment: The issue is that I need the script to work while the user is typing. I can't "force" them to publish anything.